# How to set GridViewCustomAdapter from asyncTask?

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-asynctask, android-adapter

In my app I have PostersFragment that will be a GridView with movies posters, in this fragment I need to initialize the GridView and customGridViewAdapter.
My customGridViewAdapter need to get the Bitmaps array and then work with it.
The problem that I call to AsyncTask that is in different class that gets all information from JSON and stores the information with the movies posters on local database.
I cant understand how and when to use the .setAdapter(gridViewCustomAdapter);

There is my code.

```
public class PostersFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


private GridView gv_posters;
private GridViewCustomAdapter gridViewCustomAdapter;

public PostersFragment() {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    UpdatePosters();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Log.d("TESTAG","onCreateView");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    gv_posters = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gv_posters);
    gv_posters.setAdapter(gridViewCustomAdapter);
    gv_posters.setOnScrollListener(new PostersScrollListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    gv_posters.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    // Define new adapter for grid view
    return rootView;
}
private void UpdatePosters() {
    Log.d("TESTAG","UpdatePoster");
    MoviesTask task = new MoviesTask(getActivity(),gridViewCustomAdapter);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String path = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.sort_method_posters_pref), getString(R.string.default_path));
    task.execute(path);
}
```

MoviesTask.java

```
public class MoviesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap[]> {

// Byte array to handle bitmaps
private byte[] imgByte;

// Context and custom adapter variables
private final Context mContext;
private GridViewCustomAdapter mGridCustomAdapter;

// MovieTask Constructor
public MoviesTask(Context context, GridViewCustomAdapter gridAdapter) {
    mContext = context;
    mGridCustomAdapter = gridAdapter;

}

Parsing JSON methods...

    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] bitmaps){
    Log.d("TESTAG","onPostExecute");
    if (bitmaps != null)
        mGridCustomAdapter = new GridViewCustomAdapter(mContext,R.id.single_gv_poster,bitmaps);

}
```

GridViewCustomAdapter.java

```
public class GridViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private  Context context;
int layoutResource;
private Bitmap[] bitmaps;

public GridViewCustomAdapter(Context context,int layoutResource, Bitmap[] bitmaps){
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
    this.bitmaps = bitmaps;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    viewHolder holder = null;

    if (view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResource,parent,false);

        holder = new viewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.single_gv_poster);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }else
         holder = (viewHolder)view.getTag();

    Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps[position];
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return view;
}
static class viewHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

Anyone can help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

Delete line from **onCreate()**:

gv_posters.setAdapter(gridViewCustomAdapter);

Your **PostExecute** should looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] bitmaps){
    Log.d("TESTAG","onPostExecute");
    if (bitmaps != null)
        mGridCustomAdapter = new GridViewCustomAdapter(mContext,R.id.single_gv_poster,bitmaps);
        gv_posters.setAdapter(mGridCustomAdapter);
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you.